# Good Tracking Markers with BAD Object Tracking Solution

Tags: objects, tracking, motion-capture

I'm having some trouble with object tracking.

I use a cube covered with printed dots to be my tracking object (I've tried a lot of different kind of shapes like cylinder). So far, I get bunch of good tracks, so that the marker stays on the exact point it should be. But When it comes to solving, it's a mess.

First, it didn't rotate the right way even i use perspective tracking.
Second, the perspective tracking looks fine in the camera but actually they are not.
Third, I got high error around 4~6.
[image]

Here is the file with the footage:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/19WplgpAXHwrAnZDppBlfXRJ2aYZZbfXN?usp=sharing

Here is my question:
1. What is going on? is their any way to fix it?
2. Is their a better kind of marker shape i can use?
3. What is the best shape for the tracking objects?

Thank you

Comment: don't use tripod solve and enable keyframes on the solve section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was using tripod solve, and not defining the correct span of frames to be used for the solution.

Using tripod solving does not result in accurate 3D information.

If the span of frames used for the solution is not set, blender might try to solve the object in the wrong segment of the video. Enabling the "Keyframe" option means that blender will choose what frames to use to find a solution automatically.

After turning off the tripod solve and allowing blender to define the keyframes to be used, the solve error was very low.
[image]